# Autofixture + NSubstitute: Freezing a mock?

Tags: c#, mocking, autofixture, nsubstitute

I am trying to get access to a mocked (via Nsubstitute) class that was injected onto the constructor.

I was using the following code

```
var fixture = new Fixture()
    .Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization());

var sut = fixture.Create<MyService>();
```

The sut is created sucessfully, and a mocked version of an interface called "IFileUtils" is injected on the constructor of "MyService".

but i need access to it, so after reading I believe I need to freeze the object so I have access to it like so

```
var fileUtilMock= fixture.Freeze<Mock<IFileUtils>>();
```

But this code I believe is a Moq syntax as "Mock" can't be found.

Normally to create a Nsubstitute of a class you do the following

```
var fileUtilMock= Substitute.For<IFileUtils>();
```

but of course this isn't frozen so its not used and injected into the constructor.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on inferences from [this Mocking tools comparison article by Richard Banks](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/08/mocking-comparison-part-11-multiple.html), and how  AutoMoq works, I believe:

- NSubstitute doesn't have a separation between the `Mock` and the `Mock.Object` like Moq does
- A AutoFixture.Auto* extensions hook in a `SpecimenBuilderNode` to supply the [mocked] implementation of interfaces, i.e. `fixture.Create<IFileUtils>()` should work
- Freeze is equivalent to a `var result = fixture.Create<IFileUtils>(); fixture.Inject(result)`

Therefore you should just be able to say:

```
var fileUtilMock = fixture.Freeze<IFileUtils>();
```

Comment: @daniel hilgarth are any of my inferences any good :D Feel free to edit as much as you like and/or tell me to delete the post!

Answer (score 6):

You have to *Freeze* the auto-mocked instance before creating the `MyService` instance.

**Update**:

As Ruben Bartelink points out, with NSubstitute all you have to do is:

```
var fixture = new Fixture()
    .Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization());

var substitute = fixture.Freeze<IFileUtils>();
```

..and then use NSubstitute's extension methods.

That way the same, frozen, instance will be supplied to `MyService` constructor.

**Example**:

For an interface `IInterface`:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    object MakeIt(object obj);
}
```

All you have to do with is:

```
 var substitute = fixture.Freeze<IInterface>();
 substitute.MakeIt(dummy).Returns(null);
```

`Returns` is actually an extension method in NSubstitute.

Comment: But this I believe is for Moq, I am using NSubstitute, and the Mock<IFileUtils>  - Mock isn't found or exists..